# JavaFX remove InvalidatorListener with lambda expression

Tags: java, javafx

I am using this code:

```
    renameWindow.showingProperty().addListener(new InvalidationListener() {
                @Override
                public void invalidated(Observable observable) {

                    //Remove the Invalidator Listener
                    renameWindow.showingProperty().removeListener(this);

               }
            });
```

And i want to do in lambda way and i use:

```
renameWindow.showingProperty().addListener(listener->{
                renameWindow.showingProperty().removeListener(this);
            });
```

and i am getting error cause maybe the listener is the Observable interface or what?.I want to do this using lambda expression.How can this be done?How to remove the InvalidationListener using lambda.

Comment: What is the problem? Have you tested it? Does it give an error, and if so what error? E.g. could you explain a bit more what answer you are looking for?

Comment: @n247 yes the second gives error is doesn't compile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this` refers to a instance of the class containing the code, not to the lambda expression itself.

[jls-15.27.2: Lambda Body](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.27.2)

> Unlike code appearing in anonymous class declarations, the meaning of names and the `this` and `super` keywords appearing in a lambda body, along with the accessibility of referenced declarations, are the same as in the surrounding context (except that lambda parameters introduce new names).

Therefore you're trying to call `removeListener` with a object as parameter that doesn't implement `InvalidationListener` or `ChangeListener`, which means none of the `removeListener` methods is applicable.

The only way to get a reference to the lambda expression is by using some expression access a reference to it from the lambda body that is *evaluated* at the time the lambda body is executed.

This could be done e.g. by assigning it to a field.

Example

```
private InvalidationListener listener = observable -> renameWindow.showingProperty().removeListener(this.listener);
```

Comment: I have to do InvalidationListener listener = listener->{ //code here }; that what it means the last line?

Comment: This property doesn't even provide a method to get the listener like renameWindow.showingProperty().addListener(observable -> {
     renameWindow.showingProperty().removeListener(renameWindow.showingProperty().getListener());
    }); it could be only one line code..Also why we can't access the method showingProperty()?

Comment: Property doesn't povide a method to retrieve listeners because of the information hiding principle (the user has no business knowing who **else** listens to the property). You need to store the listener it somewhere else. A `ReadOnlyBooleanProperty` (such as `showing`) provides 2 `removeListener` methods: one with a `InvalidationListener` parameter and one with a `ChangeListener<Boolean>` parameter. Since the argument you're using is `this` and the surrounding context is neither assignable to `InvalidationListener` nor to `ChangeListener<Boolean>`, you get your compile time error.